# Is it Possible to set the height smaller than 21 pixels for the System.Windows.Forms.Combobox-Control

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

**Hello Community**,

i've a problem with the height of the System.Windows.Forms.Combobox-Control. I can't change it. I want to use that to write an own implementation (owner drawn custom control).

The following code does not work for me (It's only to try). The height is still 21px!

```
public class TestBox : ComboBox
{
    public TestBox()
    {
        DropDownHeight = 15;
    }

    protected override Size DefaultSize
    {
        get
        {
            return new Size(15,15);
        }
    }

    protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, 15, 15, specified);
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Regars,
Marco

Comment: Ok, thx for the I havn't set that im my example. But it didn't work!

Comment: what about making your own combo?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the question. But thanx for your comment.

Comment: see my updated answer. Change the combo font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The ComboBox height should be resized
>   based on the **font** that is assigned to
>   it.

So, change the combo font. see [another discussion on this subject](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/78aa077e-2516-4bee-ab2d-3cf0fcae9853).

ComboBox's `MinimumSize` property is coded like this:

```
public override Size MinimumSize
{
    get
    {
        return base.MinimumSize;
    }
    set
    {
        // can see that Height is not taken in consideration - is 0
        base.MinimumSize = new Size(value.Width, 0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... the answer for my question is definitly no! If you do not want to change the font size!